# Integrate git project on an existing project startActivityForResult and onActivityResult android

Tags: java, android, function, opencv, button

I implemented this [git](https://github.com/adityaarora1/LiveEdgeDetection) on my current project without cloning

> implementation 'com.github.adityaarora1:LiveEdgeDetection:master-SNAPSHOT'

But I'm unable to call it on my method. The document says

1. Start startActivityForResult from your activity

   ```
   startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE);
   ```
2. Get a file path for cropped image on onActivityResult

   ```
   String filePath =  data.getExtras().getString(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
   Bitmap baseBitmap = ScanUtils.decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, ScanConstants.IMAGE_NAME);
   ```

So I tried calling like this onClick button from a new Class

```
   scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
```

and put the rest inside my onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
    Bitmap baseBitmap = ScanUtils.decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, ScanConstants.IMAGE_NAME);
}
```

**Edit**: here is the MainActivity the author used on git I tried using it I get this error:

> scannedImageView = findViewById(com.adityaarora.liveedgedetection.R.id.scanned_image);

**MainActivity** (imported)

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private ImageView scannedImageView;
Button scan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    scannedImageView = findViewById(com.adityaarora.liveedgedetection.R.id.scanned_image);
    startScan();

    scan = findViewById(R.id.open_scan);
        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ScanActivity2.this,
                    ScanActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent ,111);
        }
    });
}

private void startScan() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(null != data && null != data.getExtras()) {
                String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
                Bitmap baseBitmap = ScanUtils.decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, ScanConstants.IMAGE_NAME);
                scannedImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                scannedImageView.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap);
            }
        } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** :

After some research I found that the imported project was on read file only and cannot be changed (ScanActivity.java) and my current project was updated sdk 28 which is different from the one Imported so there is some errors in ScanActivity which Is why the button (technically) wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` like below.

```
scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ScanActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(myIntent ,111);
    }
});
```

and modify your `onActivityResult` like

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 111){
         String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
         Bitmap baseBitmap = ScanUtils.decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, ScanConstants.IMAGE_NAME);
         Log.d("YourTAG","File Path "+filePath);
         // here you can set bitmap to your image view 
         yourImageView.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You Main Activity should be like

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private ImageView scannedImageView;
Button scan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    scannedImageView = findViewById(R.id.scanned_image); // this  ImageView should be in your activity_scan.xml file with same id(scanned_image)
    startScan();

    scan = findViewById(R.id.open_scan);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           startScan();
        }
    });
}

private void startScan() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity2.this, ScanActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(null != data && null != data.getExtras()) {
                String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
                Bitmap baseBitmap = ScanUtils.decodeBitmapFromFile(filePath, ScanConstants.IMAGE_NAME);
                scannedImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                scannedImageView.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap);
            }
        } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo project**

I have uploaded a demo project on `Github` which is integrated `LiveEdgeDetection` library and working as expected.
To check it [go here](https://github.com/Jakir123/MyApplication)

Comment: Weird It should work but the button doesn't respond ..Did you manage to make it work within new project ?

Comment: Can you share on git ? just the needed files to launch button  I wanna compare I don't know what Im missing

Comment: Ok, let me try. I will let you know when I am done.

Comment: See my updated answer. I have shared a demo project link. You can clone or download this project and work with it. hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I see that you integrated the full project with modules and dependencies but my issue was trying to implement just the needed files just like mentioned in the git I don't know if it's the same process, if the code changes maybe that's why it wasn't working I'll have to add manually (liveedgedetection, and opencvlibrary) modules

Comment: No, I have added only two modules (liveedgedetection, and opencvlibrary) not the full project. In my project, `MainActivity` is mine not from the library.

Comment: see my `app-level Gradle` file `implementation project(':liveedgedetection')
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary340')` and see the package of my `MainActivity`(`com.rfsoftlab.myapplication`). you can change `MainActivity` as you want.

Comment: Alright thanks, I may also have found the problem check updated answer.